# Should JavaDoc go before or after a method-level annotation?

Tags: java, coding-style, annotations, javadoc

What is the recommended place to put JavaDoc for a method with an annotation? Before or after the annotation?

```
@Test
/**
 * My doc
 */
public void testMyTest(){

}
```

OR

```
/**
 * My doc
 */
@Test
public void testMyTest(){

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think it matters but second format is better. `annotations` are part of the code and play crucial role per their usage pattern. Better to keep all code related entries together.

Comment: If annotations are part of the code, can the annotations be included in the javadoc?

Comment: @Freiheit: Yes e.g.     `/**
     * This is my custom method.
     * @param param1
     * @param param2
     * @return outParam1
     * @throws BusinessException
     */`. But in this case they are not part of the code.

Comment: Not what I meant to ask, consider the example in my question. Is there JavaDoc indicating that I am using the @Test annotation?

Comment: @Freiheit: Since it is part of code, I don't think it is directly  supported [**Java Doc Specifications**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html), but I think you can create a [**taglet**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) as per your need.

Answer (score 4):

The *usual* style seems to be to have the annotation **after** the Javadoc comment.

The reason is that the annotations are part of the code, not of the documentation - why should the documentation sit inbetween.

This may not be obvious for `@Override` and `@Test`, and of course there are documentation related annotations, too. But technically, annotations are **Java code** of a particular syntax.